# Python flask app multiprocessing gives error missing required positional argument, but argument is given

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am creating a watchdog to monitor several folders on different VMs for new files, am using multiprocessing so that the tasks run at the same time. I only wrote one function which all the processes will be using but the folder paths are different.
I am using two variables and have provided them but I still get an error saying

```
{
  "message": "monitor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'saved'"
}
```

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp

def monitor(origin,saved):
    new = os.listdir(origin)
    if new:
        print(new)
    for filename in os.listdir(origin):
        src = origin+'\\'+filename
        dst = saved)+'\\'+filename
        shutil.move(src,dst)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    orig1 = 'pth_to_folder'
    orig2 = 'pth_to_folder'
    orig3 = 'path_to_folder'

    # creating processes 
    p1 = mp.Process(target=monitor, args =(orig1, saved1,))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=monitor, args =(orig2, saved2,))
    p3 = mp.Process(target=monitor, args =(orig3, saved3,))

    # starting processes 
    p1.start() 
    p2.start() 
    p3.start()

    # wait until processes are finished 
    p1.join() 
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
```

below is the error log

```
{
  "message": "monitor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'saved'"
}
```

Comment: What line causes the error? It may be helpful to include the full error stack.

Comment: please show full error. Which line produce this error?

Comment: {
  "message": "monitor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'saved'"
}

Comment: BTW, fom what I can see the processes terminate quite quickly as there is no iteration

Comment: Please show the full details of the error and of your code: where are the savedN vars defined?

Comment: I dont think that would help you answer the questions but ive added the variable definition.

Answer (score -1):

Change the special variable(**name**) line to the following,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

I tried with something like below and it's working for me,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []

    # creating processes
    for i in range(3):
        p = mp.Process(target=monitor, args=('orig'+str(i+1), 'saved'+str(i+1,)))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for job in jobs:
        job.join()
```

Comment: doesn't solve it, but thanks for your input. I appreciate the effort